# Why isn't "innard" a word?

Tags: is-it-a-word

*Innards* is defined as "the internal organs of an animal".

Then shouldn't "innard" denote a single internal organ? Or is this a case where a singular noun looks like a plural?

Comment: Why is *trousers* a word and *trouser* isn't?

Comment: @curiousdannii trouser is a word... as in trouser cuffs. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trouser

Comment: Well yes, but as an adjective not a noun. **the trouser* is clearly wrong.

Comment: @curiousdannii — depends on the dialect of English you choose. In Indian English, _a trouser_ is the same as _a pair of trousers_ elsewhere.

Comment: @oerkelens interesting. I thought I had a good simple example of the arbitrariness of English's always plural nouns but you all just keep finding more exceptions :P

Comment: 'Entrail' is considered unacceptable in some quarters, and _not licensed_ (which is different from _proscribed_) by many dictionaries.

Comment: *Innard* (inward) would be a direction; *innards* are what you find when you get there. The same as *inside* and *insides*.

Comment: Right, @bye, the same reason there isn't 'a nether'.

Comment: @JonJayObermark unless you are talking about the nether in Minecraft

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we see the word as a plural, it is what is called a [**plurale tantum**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum) or **lexical plural**.

> A plurale tantum (Latin for "plural only"; plural form: pluralia tantum) is a noun that appears only in the plural form and does not have a singular variant for referring to a single object. These are used in English for objects that function as pairs or sets (glasses, pants, scissors, clothes, electronics, bagpipes, genitals).

That does not mean there never is a singular form:

> In English, some plurale tantum nouns in fact have a singular form, but one that is used only attributively. That is, phrases such as "trouser presses" and "scissor kick" contain the singular form, even though it is considered non-standard to say "a trouser" on its own. This accords with a general preference for singular nouns in attributive positions in English; however, some words are used in the plural form even as attributive nouns (e.g. "clothes peg", "glasses case").

[Another source](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/pluraleterm.htm) also gives some nice examples and groups of words that behave like this:

> Doesn't it seem just a little loopy that we can make amends but never just one amend; that no matter how carefully we comb through the annals of history, we can never discover just one annal; that we can never pull a shenanigan, be in a doldrum, or get a jitter, a willy, a delerium tremen, a jimjam, or a heebie-jeebie?

---

**However**, according to [etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=innards), it is not necessarily a plural. As a dialectical form of **inwards**, we can read it as a plural (the singular *inward* being something on the inside, analogous to *the bowels* that etymonline mentions), or as a singular substantivised (*nouned*) [adverb](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inwards).

*Inwards* as an adverb is a variation on *inward* though, and because of the analogy with *bowels*, I *would* see it as a plural.

---

As WS2 mentions in his comment, the transformation of *inwards* to *innards* is quiet a common one. It seems the *w* following a consonant can be elided in certain words (I have heard *awfull* without a pronounced *w*) and certainly in certain dialects: the Norfolk dialect treats *backwards* as *backards*, and *forward* as *forrard*:

> *Arter I et tha' rubub, I kept a-go'rn *backards* and *forrards* to the little house at the top of the garden.

A *w* followed by a consonant is very often hardly pronounced, if at all, as in *playwright*, *well-wrought* or *awry*. It seems the *w* sound just doesn't sit well next to consonants.

Comment: Very comprehensive reply! I would only mention further the migration from *inwards* to *innards*. This is not unusual. The Norfolk dialect treats *backwards* as *backards*, and *forward* as *forrard*. * Arter I et tha' rubub, I kept a-go'rn backards and forrards to the little house at the top of the garden'

Comment: @WS2: Thank you! I stole your note and your example...

Comment: _W_ + consonant is indeed often reduced, because _r_ is basically the only consonant that can homosyllabically follow _w_, and /r/ has been rounded in the vast majority of English dialects, merging /r/ and /wr/ completely. Scottish and (some) Indian English are the only exceptions to this that I can think of (there may be others, though, but they're still a minority).

Comment: Note that "jitter" is a word, at least in technical jargon; though its not exactly the singular of "jitters".

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably in its etymology:

[Innards](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=innards&searchmode=none) (n.):

> - 1825, innerds, dialectal variant of inwards "the bowels" (c.1300).